# Flash movie in Firefox intermittently load XML with URLLoader

Tags: flash, firefox, urlloader

I have a Flash movie that behaves as follows:

Movie loads > tries to load an XML file using URLLoader.load() > uses the data in the XML to load some images into the movie.

The requirement was for updates to the XML file to be picked up within 10 minutes, so I have added a querystring parameter to the XML URL which is a timestamp to the nearest ten minutes, e.g. example.com/source.xml**?nocache=2011-0-6_11-40**

This all works for me as expected in IE and Chrome, and it works locally for me in Firefox. However, on our production server (IIS) in Firefox, the following behaviour occurs (by observing Firebug):

First load:
SWF loads > XML Requested and loads > images requested and load
Subsequent page loads:
SWF Loads > no request for the XML (no request shown in Firebug)

Firebug shows the following information about the XML file from the first successful request:

Response Headers
Cache-Control max-age=31536000
Content-Length 640
Content-Type text/xml
Content-Location http://www.example.com/portals/0/flash/slider3/list.xml?nocache=2011-0-6_11-30
Last-Modified Thu, 06 Jan 2011 08:08:12 GMT
Accept-Ranges bytes
Server Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By ASP.NET
ServedBy :9002
Date Thu, 06 Jan 2011 11:38:00 GMT
Request Headers
Host www.example.com
User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.2.13) Gecko/20101203 Firefox/3.6.13
Accept text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language en-gb,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive 115
Connection keep-alive
__utma=39412577.29609269.1294313877.1294313877.1294313877.1; __utmb=39412577; __utmc=39412577; __utmz=39412577.1294313877.1.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)

Cache
Last Modified Thu Jan 06 2011 11:38:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
Last Fetched Thu Jan 06 2011 11:38:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
Expires Fri Jan 06 2012 11:38:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
Data Size 640
Fetch Count 2
Device disk

Key: http://www.example.com/portals/0/flash/slider3/list.xml?nocache=2011-0-6_11-10
Data size: 640 bytes
Fetch count: 2
Last modified: 2011-01-06 11:01:25
Expires: 2012-01-06 11:01:25

I don't understand what would cause URLLoader to not create a request that appears in Firebug. And if it is retrieving the XML from the browser cache, why isn't the movie working (loading the images etc)?

Comment: Do you use the Flash player content debugger?  What does your log file say?

Comment: Firefox can sometimes have an issue with when the SWF is actually loaded and ready, make sure in your document class constructer you don't do anything other than wait for the stage to be available, then initialize your app. (Use Event.ENTER_FRAME listener then remove it when the stage object is not null, and stageWidth/stageHeight are greater than 0). See here: http://www.stevensacks.net/2009/01/20/firefox-3-mac-flash-bug-stagewidth-and-stageheight-are-0/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We resolved this issue - the content editor was using an XML file that did not have an XML declaration at the top, i.e.

The issue has not reappeared since we corrected the XML file.